# How to count occurrences of a string in a list column?

Tags: pyspark

[image]

I have a data frame with 2 columns: Role \ Skills. (the skills are split into a list)

I wish to find the top 10 most common skill among every skill.
How can I make a data frame that would display the count of each of these skills?
(where the first row might be 4G: 123... etc)

And the second thing I wish to accomplish is to check for overlapping skills between different roles.

So what I really want is a table where the first column is the full range of Skills and a 2nd column to count them, and a 3rd column to display a list that would display distinct Roles that has that skill in their list.

I am trying to make this work for several hours to no avail currently.

Comment: can you share what you tried and add a code to reproduce the sample data and an expected output?

Comment: and avoid adding pictures, instead directly add a sample data for the future

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the skills array and regroup. Try this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
test = spark.createDataFrame([('TL',['python','java']),('PM',['PMP','python']),('TM',['python','java','c'])],schema=['role','skill'])
test_exp = test.select('role',F.explode('skill').alias('skill'))
test_res = test_exp.groupby('skill').agg(F.count('role').alias('skill_count'),F.collect_set('role').alias('roles_associated'))


test_res.show()
+------+-----------+----------------+
| skill|skill_count|roles_associated|
+------+-----------+----------------+
|python|          3|    [PM, TL, TM]|
|     c|          1|            [TM]|
|  java|          2|        [TL, TM]|
|   PMP|          1|            [PM]|
+------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for adding the `createDataFrame` snippet.  You should switch to `spark.createDataFrame` ;)

Comment: @Powers - thanks for the hint.. it was a force of habit :-) have corrected it now